# Network Policy Server Granular Time Restrictions

Tags: radius, 802.1, nps

I am configuring NPS as a RADIUS authentication source for my wireless clients.

I am trying to differentiate between school hours and after hours as I need to connect certain users to a different network for after hours access to extra resources.

I can setup day and time restrictions but with only to the hour precision. I require at worst 30 minute intervals with 15 minute intervals being ideal.

Does anyone know if this is possible with Microsoft's NPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Step to do:

1. setup some example time restriction that GUI allows,
2. dump the NPS config
   with netsh:
   `netsh nps export filename="path\file.xml" exportPSK=YES`
   with powershell:
   `Export-NpsConfiguration -Path <filename>`
3. edit the XML file. These are the droids You are looking for (example):
   `<msNPConstraint xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" dt:dt="string">TIMEOFDAY("0 00:00-24:00; 1 00:00-02:00 03:00-24:00; 2 00:00-24:00; 3 00:00-24:00; 4 00:00-24:00; 5 00:00-24:00; 6 00:00-24:00")</msNPConstraint>`
   I removed 1 hour
   [image: removed 1 hour for example to show xml effect]
   look of denied is done: `1 00:00-02:00 03:00-24:00`
   **You can adjust to minutes in the XML not GUI.**
4. restore the NPS config from the edited XML file.
   `netsh nps import filename="path\file.xml"`

ps. In general - You can do a lot more in the XML even add things/attributes/rules that are not possible via GUI.

dump/restore reference:
http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/cc732059%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My server says the following command was not found with netsh: nps.  With powershell, it's the term 'Export-NpsConfiguration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.  NPS is installed...

Anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: figured this out.  You have to run the command prompt as administrator, even though you're already logged into the server as an administrator.